# Unexpected token, javascript =

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code

```
import request from 'request-json';

export const getAccounts = (id, api = 'https://api.domain.tld/') => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const client = request.createClient(api);

    client.get(`accounts/${id}/full`, (err, res, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

but get this error

```
node bin/server    
/home/project/src/service/account.js:13
exports.default = (id, api = 'https://api.domain.tld/') => {
                           ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

what am i missing?

Comment: Apparently your version of Node.js doesn't support [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

Comment: Since you are already using a transpiler for your module exports, you should simple transpile default initialisers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define default parameter values like that in the version of JS supported by the environment that you're running.

A common way of handling this in the past would look something like this:

```
export const getAccounts = (id, api) => {
    api = api || 'https://api.domain.tld/';
    // ...
}
```

---

EDIT:

@Maxx would prefer something like this for perfect ES2015 compatibility:

```
export const getAccounts = (id, api) => {
    if (api === undefined) {
        api = 'https://api.domain.tld/';
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thats not really the same. different result with `null` provided as `api` parameter for example

Comment: @Maxx, sure. But, the "default operator" as it's been called, has been used as a practical solution to handle defaults in many cases. I was simply offering an alternative. In any case, I admit it's not a perfect translation so I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thats ok. Just little note about it. )